# Change the default color of materialize.css input fields. I have attached screenshot

Tags: materialize

[image: Please see attachment]

I have tried to add custom css, but not worked. I need to change the color of text after selecting the input fields.

```
<div class="input-field form-group">
    <input id="first_name" class="active validate form-control" name="first_name" type="text" value="">
    <label for="first_name" class="mat-label">First Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the relevant code - otherwise it will be hard to tell what you need to change to get the desired result.

Comment: Hello Filburt, I have attached screenshot and marked it. Please check.

Comment: Can you see screenshot now?

Comment: @DipayanDas How should we identify the class/id of the input field from a screenshot?

Comment: Here is the <div>

<div class="input-field form-group">
      <input id="first_name" class="active validate form-control" name="first_name" type="text" value="">
      <label for="first_name" class="mat-label">First Name</label>
</div>

Comment: Hi I have found solution. :)

Comment: If you think the solution may be useful for other people, please add your solution as an answer (you can self-answer your question), and accept the answer.

Comment: Hi I have added solutions in answer. Please see. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

An easier way, though you should edit the SCSS files.
But if you want in quick then use the following css.
I have used royalblue color here, you can use any hex color.

For bottom border

```
input:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid royalblue !important;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 royalblue !important;
}
```

For label color

```
label.active {
  color: royalblue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the line color, I was able to change the default green to black with the css below.

```
input:not([type]):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="text"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="password"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="email"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="url"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="time"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="date"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="datetime"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="datetime-local"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="tel"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="number"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), input[type="search"]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]), textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black;
}
```

Comment: curious: what's the "input:not([type])" for?

Answer (score 3):

This green is actually `$secondary-color`

So in SASS, here is how it can be changed:

```css
$secondary-color: #FEBD09;

@import "materialize-css/sass/components/variables";
```

Answer (score 2):

> When using Sass, you can change the color scheme of your site
>   extremely quickly.

To change the style of input/form you will only have to modify the variables under *10. Forms*:
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/_variables.scss

After changing the values, you need to build the new CSS file using SASS command line

Also check out: http://materializecss.com/sass.html, http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: The thing is the primary color is supposed to be `materialize-red` but it's all green everywhere... That's quite confusing

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS, you can change colors of materialize input animated text

```
input:not([type]):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=password]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=email]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=url]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=time]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=date]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=number]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap input[type=search]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly])+label,.form-wrap textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly])+label{

    color: #4285F4; /* after animation color change css */

}
```

---

```
.form-wrap input:focus:not([type]):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="text"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="password"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]), input[type="email"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="url"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]), input[type="time"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="date"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]), input[type="datetime"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="datetime-local"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]), input[type="tel"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap input[type="number"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]), input[type="search"]:focus:not(.browser-default):not([readonly]),.form-wrap textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]){

    border-bottom: 1px solid #4285F4;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #4285F4; /* after animation color change css */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color easily by changing the code like

```
<div class="input-field form-group">
<input id="first_name" class="active validate form-control" name="first_name" type="text" value="">
<label for="first_name" class="mat-label">
<span class="black-text">First Name</span>
</label>
</div>
```

That is append **-text** to the color class. Check : **http://materializecss.com/color.html**